# Запрос с данными в формате JSON

Tags: javascript, json, get

В первом примере я получаю в ответ JSON данные и все хорошо - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWgNrE?editors=1111

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://randomuser.me/api/');
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4) console.log(request.responseText);
  };
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.send();
```

Но здесь почему-то данные уже не приходят, хотя по ссылке такой же JSON объект - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmbZbL?editors=1111

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback');
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4) console.log(request.responseText);
  };
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.send();
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) ?

Comment: Извините? Не понял. И тот, и тот источник ведь ко мне никакого отношения не имеют. Это чужие сайты.

Comment: зато один может разрешать доступ, а другой нет. Код-то только ссылкой различается? а то про объект вы написали, а про код нет.

Comment: Я же могу по ссылкам напрямую в браузере пройти и получить объект. Что тогда нужно менять, чтобы во втором примере получить объект?

Comment: напрямую вы обычный запрос делаете а не `ajax`. Что делать - изучить документацию `yahooapis` на предмет того можно ли и как работать с этим через ajax. Возможно использовать `jsonp`, и в качестве последнего средства написать _прокси_ скприт на своем сервер (вы запрашиваете свой скрипт, а он в свою очередь запрашивает сторонний ресурс).